# Adding Different Objects To An ArrayList of Objects For Different Levels Only Working For One Level [Slick2D]

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, slick2d

I am creating a game where each level has different `Enemies` which are circle shapes. For the first level in the `Play` class in the `init` method I call on a class which adds the circles to the `ArrayList`, and I have it so that once the `Player` reaches the end of the level, a variable called `level` increases by 1, the `Player` respawns, the `ArrayList` clears and it calls on the circle adding class with an updated level variable.

For some reason, after adding the new circles the program shuts down. I have tried having it so that in the init method I have if statements which determine the value of `level`, but I could not find a way to call on the `init` method more than once. I have tried other things, but nothing seems to work. This Adding circles method was my last attempt before asking you guys for help.

Here is my `Play` Class:

```
 package tricky.game;
import java.util.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.*;
public class Play extends BasicGameState{

public Shape border,bg,sZone,eZone;
public Player p;
public Options o;
public int level = 1;
public addCircles a;

public Play(int play){
}
@Override
public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    sZone = new Rectangle(280,180,100,100);
    eZone = new Rectangle(820,520,100,100);
    border = new Rectangle(380,180,440,440);
    bg= new Rectangle(0,0,1200,800);

    a = new addCircles();

    p = new Player();
    p.init(container, sbg);

    o = new Options();

    a.setLevel(level);
    a.setCircles();

}
@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    Input input = container.getInput();

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fill(bg);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("X: "+input.getMouseX()+"\t Y: "+input.getMouseY(), 50, 50);   
    g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    g.fill(border);
    g.fill(sZone);
    g.fill(eZone);
    g.setLineWidth(3f);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.draw(border);
    g.draw(sZone);
    g.draw(eZone);
    g.resetLineWidth();
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("START",302,225);
    g.drawString("END",854,564);
    p.render(container, sbg, g);
    o.render(container, sbg, g);
    g.drawString("Level:"+level,540,135);
    g.drawString("ArrayList size:"+a.circle.size(),540,100);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.circle.size(); i++) {
        a.circle.get(i).render(container, sbg, g);
    }

}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = container.getInput();

    p.update(container, sbg, delta);
    o.update(container, sbg, delta);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.circle.size(); i++) {
        a.circle.get(i).update(container, sbg, delta);
        if(p.getHB().intersects(a.circle.get(i).getCircle())){
            p.respawn();
        }
    }

    if(p.getHB().intersects(eZone)){ 
        level++;
        a.circle.clear();
        p.respawn();
        a.setLevel(level);
        a.setCircles();
    }

    if(p.getHB().intersects(border) && !(p.getHB().intersects(sZone))){
        p.setBorders(381,180,820,620);
    }
    if(p.getHB().intersects(sZone) && !(p.getHB().intersects(border))){
        p.setBorders(280,180,820,280);
    }
    if(p.getHB().intersects(sZone) && (p.getHB().intersects(border))){
        p.setBorders(380,180,820,280);
    }

}




    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Here is my `Enemies` Class

```
package tricky.game;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.*;
public class Enemies {

private float x,y,maxX,maxY,minX,minY; 
public boolean dir=false;
private Shape circle;
public int type,radius;
public Enemies(int x,int y,int maxX,int minX,int maxY,int minY,int type,int radius,boolean dir){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.maxX=maxX;
    this.minX=minX;
    this.maxY=maxY;
    this.minY=minY;
    this.type=type;
    this.radius=radius;
    this.dir=dir;
}
public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{

}

public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{

    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fill(circle);
    g.setLineWidth(1.5f);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.draw(circle);
    g.resetLineWidth();
}

public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

    circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);
    if(type==1){
        if (!dir) {
            x+=4;
        } 
        if (x>=maxX) {
            dir=true;
        }      
        if (dir) {
            x-=4;
        }   
        if (x<=minX) {
            dir=false;
        }
    }
    if(type==2){
        if (!dir) {
            y+=4;
        } 
        if (y>=maxY) {
            dir=true;
        }      
        if (dir) {
            y-=4;
        }   
        if (y<=minY) {
            dir=false;
        }
    }

    if(type==3){
        if(!dir){
            y+=4;
            x+=4;
        }
        if(y>=maxY-20 && x>=maxX-20){
            dir=true;
        }
        if(dir){
            y-=4;
            x-=4;
        }

        if(y<=minY+20 && x<=minX+20){
            dir=false;
        }
    }
}
   public Shape getCircle(){
        return circle;
    }

}
```

And here is my `addCircles` class:

```
package tricky.game;

import java.util.*;
public class addCircles {
    public ArrayList<Enemies> circle = new ArrayList();
    public int level;

    public void setLevel(int level){
        this.level = level;
    }


    public void setCircles(){
        if(level==1){
            circle.add(new Enemies(420,220,780,420,0,0,1,20,false));
            circle.add(new Enemies(780,580,780,420,0,0,1,20,true));
            circle.add(new Enemies(600,260,0,0,540,260,2,20,false));
        }
        if(level==2){
            circle.add(new Enemies(600,400,820,380,620,180,3,20,false));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: What I mean by shut down is it gives me the following error:

```
Mon Jan 15 08:40:03 EST 2018 ERROR:null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.newdawn.slick.geom.ShapeRenderer.validFill(ShapeRenderer.java:94)
    at org.newdawn.slick.geom.ShapeRenderer.fill(ShapeRenderer.java:107)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Graphics.fill(Graphics.java:554)
    at tricky.game.Enemies.render(Enemies.java:29)
    at tricky.game.Play.render(Play.java:63)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.render(StateBasedGame.java:199)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:688)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at tricky.game.TrickyGame.main(TrickyGame.java:32)
Mon Jan 15 08:40:03 EST 2018 ERROR:Game.render() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.render() failure - check the game code.
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:691)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at tricky.game.TrickyGame.main(TrickyGame.java:32)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

EDIT 2: I have figured out that the action of rendering the new Enemies onto the screen is what breaks the program. I finished the first level, added the new Enemies object in and it works, just for some reason the program doesn't want to render it.

EDIT 3: I fixed everything. It was the way I was rendering the objects. I was using `g.draw()` and now I'm using `g.fillOval()`

Comment: What do you mean by: "...new circles the program shuts down" an exception? Could you provide the stacktrace please. Btw: You do not have to call the init methode multiple times you should create a load Method which contains all the if's and put that into your init method. Afterwards you need to detect a level change and call that method again.

Comment: It doesn't come up with an error, it just stops and says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" in the output. And what you suggested is what I tried to do with the `addCrircles` class. But I haven't tried calling on it in the init method, I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: Turns out it does come up with an error; it's in my main post as an edit. And I remembered incorrectly, I did call on the `addCircles` class in my `init` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue I was having. For some reason when rendering using the `g.draw()` function, the program didn't want to render it. I am now using the `g.drawOval() function` and everything works perfectly.